# Using Response from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Here's the code I have right now:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "response.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("op=login_new");

var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp2.open("POST", "verify.php", true);
xhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp2.send("content=" + xhttp.response);
```

This line appears to be the problem:

```
xhttp2.send("content=" + xhttp.response);
```

Basically I'm wanting to take the response from the first `XMLHttpRequest` and send a POST request containing that response to the second one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't use the first response until it is received. Same way you can't eat a pizza before it is delivered

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous, you can do it like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function (response) {
  var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.open("POST", "verify.php", true);
  xhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp2.send("content=" + response);
};

xhttp.open("POST", "response.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("op=login_new");
```